# Problema con enlace Json en function R

Tags: json, r

Sabiendo que lo que va despues del **offset=** es la paginación, cómo podría dejar esta función en un solo elemento y no tener que usar rbind
Muchas gracias.
Este es el código

```
 mlb_scrape <- function() {
    
     
     team_url  <- ("https://bdfed.stitch.mlbinfra.com/bdfed/stats/player?stitch_env=prod&season=2021&sportId=1&stats=season&group=hitting&gameType=R&offset=0&sortStat=onBasePlusSlugging&order=desc&playerPool=")
     raw_mlb <- jsonlite::fromJSON(team_url)
     df0 <- purrr::pluck(raw_mlb ,"stats") %>%
     dplyr::as_tibble()
     
     team_url1  <- ("https://bdfed.stitch.mlbinfra.com/bdfed/stats/player?stitch_env=prod&season=2021&sportId=1&stats=season&group=hitting&gameType=R&offset=25&sortStat=onBasePlusSlugging&order=desc&playerPool=")
     raw_mlb1 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(team_url1)
     df1 <- purrr::pluck(raw_mlb1 ,"stats") %>%
       dplyr::as_tibble()
     df <- rbind(df0, df1)
df
   }   
  df <- mlb_scrape()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya sabes que los offsets son cada 25 lo primero sería hacer una secuencia desde 0 hasta el último elemento que quieres escrapear, con intervalos de 25. En este caso voy hasta el valor 100, pero podrías hacerlo más largo.

```
library(jsonlite)
offset <- seq(0, 100, 25)
```

Luego puedes crear de antemano las urls que vas a visitar. Con `paste0` pegas la parte fija de la url con la parte que cambia (el número de offset).

```
urls <- paste0("https://bdfed.stitch.mlbinfra.com/bdfed/stats/player?stitch_env=prod&season=2021&sportId=1&stats=season&group=hitting&gameType=R&offset=", 
               offset, 
               "&sortStat=onBasePlusSlugging&order=desc&playerPool=")
```

Con las urls armadas puedes usar un iterador como `map()` para pasar por cada url y descargar el objeto `json`. Eso armará una lista, cada elemento de esa lista es el `json` que corresponde a cada url.

```
library(tidyverse)
map(urls, ~fromJSON(.x)) -> crudos
```

Si lo que te interesa es el data.frame `stats` que está en cada json puedes usar de nuevo `map()` para extraerlos. En este caso uso `map_dfr` que se encarga automáticamente de combinar el resultado en un solo data.frame. No hace falta en `rbind()`

```
map_dfr(crudos, "stats") -> df

df %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 125 x 71
   year  playerId playerName type   rank playerFullName playerFirstName
   <chr>    <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <chr>          <chr>          
 1 2021    545361 Mike Trout play…     1 Mike Trout     Michael        
 2 2021    660670 Ronald Ac… play…     2 Ronald Acuna … Ronald         
 3 2021    502110 J.D. Mart… play…     3 J.D. Martinez  Julio
```

Se podría ubicar dentro de una función, pero no creo que haga falta. Son 4 líneas.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad, pero es justo eso; quiero hacerme un package y tener esa función  para que cada vez que la llame se carguen los data frame. Genial. es justo lo que necesito